# count(*) doesn't return 0

Tags: sql, count, left-join, full-outer-join

i have a sql problem ,please help me this is my query

```
  select count(category_value .list_value_id) as jobs , category_type.value as category
from list_values category_type
full outer join params category_value
on category_type.list_value_id = category_value .list_value_id
join qrtz_triggers jobs
on category_value .object_id = jobs.job_name
and jobs.trigger_state ='PAUSED'
and category_value.attr_id = 9158075153713931109
where category_type.attr_type_def_id = 9158075154713931109
group by category_type.value;
```

attr_id is list value which contains 9158075158713931109(non-critical) and 9158075157713931109(critical)

```
returns result:
JOBS,   CATEGORY
2        Non-Critical


expected result is :
JOBS,   CATEGORY
2        Non-Critical
0          Critical

list_values table conains
list_value_id          values
9158075158713931109     non-critical
9158075157713931109      critical


params table
list_value_id          attr_id                         object_id
9158075158713931109     9158075153713931109           a
9158075157713931109      9158075153713931109          b
9158075157713931109      9158075153713931109          c
9158075158713931109     9158075153713931109           d

qtz_trigger table  i need triggers with state "paused"

job_name            trigger_state 
b                     paused
a                     paused
e                     normal
c                     paused
```

I even tried for category_value .object_id in  (select jobs.job_name from qrtz_triggers jobs where jobs.trigger_type ='SIMPLE')   but getting error command not properly ended

Comment: MySQL does not support  `full outer join`. Are you sure that this is the database you are using?

Comment: Regarding your "command not properly ended" syntax error: please remove all spaces: `category_value.list_value_id` (vs. "category_value .list_value_id:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you actually want `left join`s, starting from the `list_values` table and then brining `params` and `qrtz_triggers`:

```
select count(t.job_name) as jobs, v.value as category
from list_values v
left join params p
    on  p.list_value_id = v.list_value_id
    and p.attr_id       = v.attr_type_def_id
left join qrtz_triggers t
    on  t.job_name      = p.object_id
    and t.trigger_state = 'PAUSED'
where v.attr_type_def_id = 9158075154713931109
group by v.value;
```

The conditions were a bit messy in the originaly query so I tried to re-arrange that - you might need to review that. I also used short and representative table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

This filtering condition:

```
where category_type.attr_type_def_id = 9158075154713931109
```

is going to turn the `full join` into a left or right join.

Filtering with `full join`s is quite tricky.  I'm not sure that `full join` is needed -- your question doesn't explain what you are really trying to do.  However, if you really do need `full join`, I find that filtering in a subquery usually does what I want.

Comment: i need a query to get trigger with state 'paused' in that count of  triggers that are critical(9158075157713931109 ) and non-critical(9158075158713931109 )